# Is there a finite non-regular ring which is a direct product of local rings with atleast one not a field?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, free-modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. $R$ is regular if for each $a\in R$, there exists $b\in R$ such that $a=aba$.  It is local it has a unique maximal ideal.

(James L. Fisher , *Finite Principal Ideal Ring*, Canad. Math. Bull. Vol. 19 (3), 1976)  proves the following:

THEOREM 2. Let $R$ be a finite principal ideal ring. Then $R$ is an ideal direct sum $R_1\oplus\cdots \oplus R_k\oplus N$ where $R_i, i = l,\ldots, k$ are primary principal ideal rings and $N$ is a nilpotent principal ideal ring.

I am trying to check for examples of commutative rings satisfying this results but most of them are regular ring.

**My question:** is there an example of a finite non-regular ring which is direct product of local rings one of which is a field and the other is not a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such rings exist, and I will give you a quick recipe and idea for how to build these gadgets. It is known that commutative unital ring $A$ is von Neumann regular if and only if $A$ is both Artinian (zero-dimensional) and reduced (so in particular every prime ideal is maximal and $A$ admits no non-zero nilpotents). Because finite rings are automatically Artinian (you cannot have infinitely many non-equal ideals of a finite ring --- use the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to give an upper bound on how many such ideals you can have) you can generate finite non-regular commutative unital rings $A$ by violating the reduced requirement that von Neumann regularity forces.

Here is an explicit example. Fix an integer prime $p$, an integer $n$ with $n \geq 2$, and consider the ring
$$
A := \mathbb{F}_{p} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^n\mathbb{Z}}.
$$
Both $\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ are local rings (as $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ has unique maximal ideal $(p) = \mathfrak{m}$) but $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field. In particular, $p$ is nilpotent of nilpotency index $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, because $A$ is non-reduced, $A$ is a product of local rings (one a field and one not a field) that is finite and not von Neumann regular.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put aside finiteness for a second.

You have two things going for you:

1. Every single local ring that isn't a division ring is not regular
2. A product is regular iff the rings involved are regular

So **any** product of local rings is an example (sometimes infinite) **as long as** you pick one of them to not be a division ring.

Convenient examples of nonfield local rings are, for example:

1. Localizations of a nonfield PID at any maximal ideal (e.g. $\mathbb Z$ localized at the complement of $(2)$)
2. Quotients of a PID by a power (greater than 1) of a maximal ideal (e.g. $\mathbb Z/(4)$)

To make it finite, you just choose finite rings.  (Like something in the second point above.)

Just so my answer suggests a finite local ring which hasn't already been suggested: $F_2[x,y]/(x,y)^2$ is a finite local ring, where $F_2$ is the field of two elements.